# Xcode version to develop for iphone4G

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to start development with iphone 4 and iphone 4s, What is the Xcode version should I download?
Note: I am using MAC OS Snow leopard

Comment: This information isn't directly available from developer.apple.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Snow Leopard you can only download (from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), requires registration) version 4.2

v4.3.1 required OSX Lion (I suggest you download that, since Apple stopped updating Xcode for Snow Leopard)

Comment: Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard is available in the iOS Dev Center at https://developer.apple.com

Comment: Is Xcode 4.3 available for Snow Leopard? Or do you mean 4.2?

Answer (score 3):

The latest Xcode version you can use on Snow Leopard is Xcode 4.2. And you can use this version for iPhone 4 and 4S development.

However note that Xcode 4.2 doesn't include iOS 5.1 sdk. So my advice is to get Lion and Xcode 4.3.1.